# How do I make different types of ol horizontally in one line?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have to make all 5 types of ordered list in one line like whats shown in the picture here[image: Example of what I need help with]

```
<h2> Types of Ordered list</h2>
    <ol Type="1">
            <li>Black & Blue</li>
            <li>The man from Toronto</li>
            <li>Central Intelligence</li>
    </ol>

    <ol Type="a">
            <li>September</li>
            <li>October</li>
            <li>November</li>
    </ol>
    <ol Type="A">
            <li>Black</li>
            <li>Red</li>
            <li>Purple</li>
     </ol>
     <ol Type="i">
            <li>Winter</li>
            <li>Fall</li>
            <li>Spring</li>
     </ol>
    <ol Type="I">
            <li>Apple</li>
            <li>Orange</li>
            <li>Watermelon</li>
     </ol>
```

```
ol, li{
    list-style-position: inside;
    color:whitesmoke;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;

}
```

If anyone have any idea on how to fix it please help me and thanks

Answer (score 0):

All list elements can be wrapped in a single div, then aligned center using `justify-content` with the `display` set to `flex`.

```css
.lists{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<h2> Types of Ordered list</h2>
<div class='lists'>
    <ol Type="1">
            <li>Black & Blue</li>
            <li>The man from Toronto</li>
            <li>Central Intelligence</li>
    </ol>

    <ol Type="a">
            <li>September</li>
            <li>October</li>
            <li>November</li>
    </ol>
    <ol Type="A">
            <li>Black</li>
            <li>Red</li>
            <li>Purple</li>
     </ol>
     <ol Type="i">
            <li>Winter</li>
            <li>Fall</li>
            <li>Spring</li>
     </ol>
    <ol Type="I">
            <li>Apple</li>
            <li>Orange</li>
            <li>Watermelon</li>
     </ol>
</div>
```